# Swift allow user to choose player Sprite Node

Tags: swift

I'm trying to allow the user to select their preferred player type/design.

In my gameScene I simply have 1 SKSpriteNode with a texture however I'd like the user to have the option to select between 3 different players.

The only way I can think of doing this is to have the 3 player options all linked to their own gameScene.. And when the user selects the preferred player it will transition to the related gameScene?

The 3 gameScenes would be identical, only that the texture for the player SpriteNode would be different.

This doesn't seem very efficient at all. But I'm a novice and just trying to use knowledge I've gathered so far.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely sure how to interpret your question, here goes!

I would recommend creating a bit of logic to allow you to insert the avatar in the selection scene, as well as your game scene.

```
extension SKSpriteNode {
    enum AvatarType {
        case blueMan
        case purpleWizard
        case greyDinosaur
    }

    class func avatar(withType type: AvatarType) -> SKSpriteNode {
        let spriteName: String
        switch type {
        case .blueMan:
            spriteName = "blueManSprite"
        // case .purpleWizard
        //   ...
        default:
            spriteName = "someSprite"
        }

        return SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: spriteName)
    }
}
```

In your `SKScene` subclasses (or anywhere of course ;) ), you can create avatars like so:

```
class ChooseAvatarScene : SKScene {
    let avatarBlueMan = SKSpriteNode.avatar(withType: .blueMan)
    // let avatarWizard = ...
    // let avatarDinosaur = ...

    func setup() {
        avatarBlueMan.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
        // avatarWizard.position = ...
        // avatarDinosaur.position = ...

        addChild(avatarBlueMan)
        addChild(avatarWizard)
        addChild(avatarDinosaur)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // check if any of the touches hit an avatar sprite
    }
}
```

Of course, the sprite nodes need to be put in the right position. After that, you need to implement touch handling so register when the user touches a node.

The benefit of this approach is that the Avatar nodes are reusable across different scenes - so if you would want to change the sprite for the wizard, there's only one place you have to change it.
Note that the SKSpriteNode extension in the example is *very* simple - if you want anything more than a single sprite I would recommend subclassing SKSpriteNode instead.